# Sorting elasticsearch types based on child type property

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I'm working on a e-commerce search page and need to free text search products and have multiple facet options and sorting capabilities. The issue I'm facing has to do with product prices:
One product has multiple prices - there are special discounts, B2B customer specific prices, and specific B2C prices. There could be a few hundred prices per product.

I need to be able to do to a full text search on products, but still be able to sort on one of the selected price groups.

My initial though would be to put all of the prices into the product item, but that means I'll need to update the product objects in the index every time a price changes - which is often. This will also make the objects quite big.

I see that elasticsearch now has the capability of HasParent/HasChildren queries, but I am not sure if that is the right way to go, or if it even is possible. 
Is it possible to keep prices as a separate type outside the product type and use the HasParent/HasChilden queries to sort the procuts on the price?

Answer (score 0):

> My initial though would be to put all of the prices into the product item, but that means I'll need to update the product objects in the index every time a price changes - which is often. This will also make the objects quite big.

I would personally be inclined not to store complex pricing data within Elasticsearch, at least not prices calculated by business logic such as discounts and specific B2C prices.

A base price could be stored for querying and sorting, and apply pricing logic to this with scripting, using [script queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-query.html) and [script sorting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/search-request-sort.html#_script_based_sorting), respectively.

> I see that elasticsearch now has the capability of HasParent/HasChildren queries, but I am not sure if that is the right way to go, or if it even is possible. Is it possible to keep prices as a separate type outside the product type and use the HasParent/HasChilden queries to sort the procuts on the price?

Parent/Child relationships operate on documents within a single index, with a [join datatype](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/parent-join.html) field on a document to indicate the relationship between a parent and a child, and child documents indexed on the same shard as the parent. If children are not evenly distributed across parents/shards e.g. one parent document has a million children and the others have only a few each, it's possible to end up with hot spots within shards that *can* affect performance. Product and pricing data doesn't *feel* like a good fit for Parent/Child; pricing sounds like it's too dynamic to be stored within documents.